# Find files in order of modification time

Tags: time, find, alphabetical

I have a certain shell script like this:

for name in `find $1 -name $2 -type f -mmin +$3`
do 
Filename=`basename "ls $name"`
echo "$Filename">>$1/order.txt
done

find command returns N number of files in alphabetical order. Their names are inserted into order.txt in alphabetical order. How to change this into the order of modification time?

i.e., if file F2 was modified first then file F1, then the above script enters first F1 then F2 into order.txt as per alphabetical order. But I want F2 to be entered first then F1, that is as per order of modification time

I want order.txt after the script to be 
Order.txt=>
F2
F1

and not as 
F1
F2

Please help

Answer (score 1):

`find` has an `-exec` switch, allowing you to pass any matched filenames to an external command:

```
find $1 -name $2 -type -mmin +$3 -exec ls -1t [-r] {} +
```

With this, `find` will pass all of the matching files at once to `ls` and allow that to do the sorting for you. With the optional `-r` flag, files will be printed in order of oldest to newest; without, in order of newest to oldest.

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in `find $1 -name $2 -type f -mmin +$3`
do 
ftime=$(stat -c %Y $name)
Filename=`basename "ls $name"`
echo "$ftime $Filename"
done | sort -n | awk '{print $2}' > $1/order.txt
```

One way: get file mtimes in seconds since epoch, sort on seconds since epoch, then print only the filename

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/22227cfc6a604c837baceb65f5e92216b2669856/.bash_aliases#L38):

```
find_date_sorted() {
    # Ascending, by ISO date
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
    do
        cut -d ' ' -f 3- <<< "$REPLY"
    done 9< <(find ${1+"$@"} -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %p\0' | sort -z)
}
```